# Screen resolution

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

Today I try to change the screen resolution of my computer with the recommended resolution in my monitor and to do that I download a program that I saw It in a Tutorial video , and when I chose this resolution the software change also the frequency and the Monitor turn off and when I reboot the PC after had the same problem (the screen became black) , I'm now under linux I can't use windows due to this problem can I change the screen resolution without turning on windows (change some files link linux...)

Comment: Start Windowds in Safe Mode (Pressing F5 upon start) may help.

Comment: What tutorial did you follow and what program did you download? There is no reason you should need to download any program to use the native display modes on any monitor since 2005.

Comment: thank you guys I had fix this problem by clicking F8 to start the safe mode.